# Why docker restart recognizes modifications in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new in docker and docker-compose. I am working on a project which uses both docker and docker compose. After adding a line in the key "volumes" of docker-compose.yml. I did docker restart

```
docker restart service1
```

and the volume was automatically recognized. Below part of the docker-compose.yml

```
services: 
  service1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.service1
    container_name: service1_name
    hostname: service1_name
    volumes:
      - /etc/teste/service1/conf.d/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/ #I added this line
```

My question Why docker restart recognizes modifications in docker-compose.yml file, where can I find this "setting"?

Comment: you restarted the docker daemon or docker-compose service and do you mind elaborating your ask, It's confusing

Comment: @Akshaybarahate I did docker restart service1

Comment: Can you state if you are running your service with "docker-compose start service1" if so, you should restart your service with docker-compose too, like "docker-compose restart service1"

Answer (score 0):

Working with docker-compose the scenario should be the following:

- Create your docker-compose.yml
- docker-compose up # this will build everything and run your services

If you make any changes to your compose file, stating docker-compose build 'yourservicename' will rebuild that specific service.

The command "docker restart" as you can see in the help page is for restarting containers